# Interrupted method when user pushes home button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, methods, lifecycle

What happens when a user pushes the home button on the iOS device and the app is currently running a method: Will the method finish running or will the method be interrupted in the middle?

Comment: - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application gets called.
I would imaging the method that you are conerned about finishes, but any callbacks and such may or may not be respected

Comment: Try it. Put print statements at the top and bottom of a method which is continuously called and then press them home button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Maudicus wrote, `applicationWillResignActive:` is called on the application delegate, as well as `applicationDidEnterBackground:`. You should assume that any method that is currently running will be interrupted. If you want to ensure that a particular operation is performed, you should put it in one of the aforementioned methods.

Comment: The method will not be interrupted unless it is a really long operation. I forget the timeout period, but you are given a limited amount of time to clean up for backgrounding. That timeout is the same whether the code is in the currently running method or if it's moved to one of the backgrounding methods. If the code takes too long to finish, it will be aborted regardless of which method it's in. So, you gain nothing by moving it to a backgrounding method.